# Is there a way to add decimal point to data in a row when outputting an sqlite3 database to CSV

Tags: python, sqlite

I am exporting a small sqlite database to csv and have a column with GPS coordinates, but the gps coordinates are missing the decimal point e.g. -277202900 instead of -27.7202900.
is there a way to add the decimal point when exporting to CSV?

I have googled everywhere for hours, the coordinates are stored in the database as an integer.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas.io.sql as sql
con = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
table = pandas.read_sql('select * from some_table', con)
table.to_csv('output.csv')
```

edit. [This is a screenshot of the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS7Xy.png) The database is on my metal detector and i can export to CSV easily enough, but it is very time consuming editing each cell.
Copy of database is here. [Database](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZbVbX5iDFatLMxJqEd5K92iQdu8EWiQ_)

Comment: `value /= 1e7`?

Comment: `the coordinates are stored in the database as an integer` ... then there is no decimal component.  Maybe show us more data and what you want here.